# Use regex to match a valid sentence

Tags: regex

I have used this regex to match a valid sentence:

It serves the purpose to validate a sentence - *(by definition)*

1. starts with Capital letter(s)
2. no punctuations in the middle of sentence, and
3. it ends with one or more of the punctuations.  (eg. ?!)
   (because the 2nd part is very similar with 3rd part, except *negation*)

The question I have - is there a way to make it more concise?

```py
/[A-Z]+[^\.?!][\.?!]+/  

# will match all the sentences:
s1 =  "A boy likes to read books."
s2 = "ABBA is one of the best musical bands."
s3 =  "Are you kidding me?!" 

# but not these sentences:
s4 = "City leaders allocated the first half of the ARPA funding to a series of initiatives,"
s5 = "will you abide the new law?"
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood what are you looking for? It looks concise enough and it is working?

Comment: Yes. It's working fine.  Just thought there maybe some other *consice* syntax... Thanks.

Comment: I tested your pattern on regex101 and its doesnt match any case. I see it only match some case like : `AAAAb?` or `Ab...`. You may misses a `*` or `+` behinds `[^.?!]`

Comment: I have checked ```regex101``` with /gm flag set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few way:

- You don't need to escape the dot in character classes, so `[\.]` is the same as `[.]`
- You only need 1 capital letter at the start (can remove the plus)
- You can use *reluctant* quantifier `.*?` (as little as possible)

This should work:

```
[A-Z].*?[.?!]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/FvclWAMXm7ploI).

Consider removing the `+`, unless you really need to match sentences that end with `??` or `?!` or `!!!` etc.

Comment: No. The `BBA` in `ABBA` is matched by `.*?`

Comment: The author doesn't want punctuations in the middle of sentences, so `.` wont work.

Comment: Doesn't this violates rule 2?

Comment: @dinhit yes, it will work. `.*?` stops matching at the first punctuation. Please post a link to a regex test site with an example of input this regex doesn't work for, if you can.

Comment: @JorgeCampos no, it does not. See my other comment

Comment: @Bohemian my bad, I have just learned about the `.*?` today.

Comment: @dinhit I added a link to a live demo showing 2 matches for `This is a sentence. This is too!!`

Comment: @JorgeCampos  I added a link to a live demo showing 2 matches for `This is a sentence. This is too!!`

Comment: Interesting that's another way of see it, I guess OP accepted it should be ok. Was not thinking of two sentences in the same line :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modified regex from your current regex

```
^[A-Z][\w\s]*[.?!]+$
```

- `^[A-Z]`: starts with uppercase character
- `[\w\s]*`: match any word characters and space in the middle (no punctuations)
- `[.?!]+$`: ends with punctuation `.`, `?`, `!` one or more time

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cOvMhe/1) example

Note: consider remove the start of line `^` and end of line `$` anchors if it doesnt fit your case

Comment: `\w` will also match `_` depending on whether OP consider it a valid character this also violates rule 2

Comment: Not sure what does the OP consider as punctuation, some work around are replace [\w\s]*` set with `[^[author punctuation set]]*` or add things not character but OP wants to match (eg: `-`) to `[\w\s]*` set

Comment: Yeap that's the reason I asked on the comment section his regex was already ok (besides the fact that the `+` should be after the `[^.!?]`)